# Using Reducer from NPM package and get access to store.getState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Super new to react/redux. Want to know how something like this can be achieved.
Created a NPM package which offers two things

- Exposes a reducer
- A simple typescript function that checks something on the store properties that the reducer is setting up. (This is where I am facing issues)

In the Consuming App

- Combined the application reducers and reducer from the NPM package
- OnLoad firing up the reducer from npm package and setting up the application store

Want to access the application store in my typescript/javascript function and wanted to how can this be done?
Using Redux/typescript

This is what i have in in my npm code

1. Reducer

   `const npmReducers = combineReducers({
   npmgetReducer: someNpmReducer
   });

   export default npmReducers;`
2. Typescript function

   ```
   export function SomeCheck(testString : string) : boolean{

    let state = <appsstore>.getState();
     //Do some checks on the state set by the npm reducer

     return true/false;
   ```

   }

This is what i have in in my application code

```
const applicationReducers = combineReducers({
npmReducers,
applicationReducer_1: appRed_1,
applicationReducer_2: appRed_2,
});
export default applicationReducers;
export type ApplicationRootState = ReturnType<typeof applicationReducers>
```

Comment: What you're describing is certainly possible in general. Can you clarify what actual problems you're having doing that, if any?

Comment: You'll need to pass the actual store instance to `SomeCheck` as an argument, if `SomeCheck` lives in your npm package.

Comment: @markerikson The issue I am having is that I am not able to grab the store initialized by the application in the npm package. let state = <appsstore>.getState(); what would be the best way to get access to the appstore?

Comment: @fireholster : Closest answer I have would be to either write this logic as thunks, or expose some kind of a setter so that the app can inject the store. But generally logic that's in a library won't have any idea what the actual store is, because that's an app concern.

Comment: @markerikson Thanks for the inputs. This is an internal private npm where we are looking to dictate some state objects by merging them with their app store. I think we need to look at it differently. We will offer them a react component from npm instead of JavaScript function instead and maybe use UseStore().getState()